# Not able to find dependency for fop command in Yocto

Tags: xml, xslt, yocto, apache-fop

I'm trying to convert XML file into PDF format using xsltproc & fop tool.

I've created recipe for this in yocto.

```
do_install {
    xsltproc /usr/share/xml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets/fo/docbook.xsl Sample.xml > Sample.fo
    fop -fo Sample.fo -pdf Sample.pdf
 }
```

I'm getting error that "fop" command not found. I tried to search for dependent packages for "fop" but I didn't get it.

Question is how to use "fop" command in yocto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a tool to be available on the build host, you should add this to a variable called `HOSTTOOLS`, that way bitbake will verify that it's present on the machine you are building on and make it available for recipes to use.

See https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-HOSTTOOLS for documentation on `HOSTTOOLS`.

Note that it should be added to global configuration, like local.conf, and not in a specific recipe.

If you don't want to add any extra requirements on the build host system, you can add a recipe which build the `fop` tool in Yocto. Then you could make your recipe depend on `fop-native`, and it will work on any machine regardless if `fop` is installed or not. This is the cleaner way of doing it, but might require some extra work if `fop` has a lot of dependencies for which recipe don't already exist. Adding it to `HOSTTOOLS` is not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have fop on your host machine(where you build Yocto). If you run from a docker you might need to install it before running bitbake.

Comment: this is not how yocto or openembedded works (by default). Even native tools are built and used from within the build system itself, in other words build host dependencies are not used except in specific cases -- Eriks answer shows that specific case.